# Firefox extension using declarativeNetRequest not work - Extension works on Chrome

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, browser-extension

I have made a browser extension that redirects image links on a forum. The extension works perfectly fine on Chromium, but it does not work on the latest version of Firefox (version 116).

Manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "name",
  "version": "1.1",
  "description": "description",
  "permissions": [
    "declarativeNetRequestWithHostAccess"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "https://www.example.net/discussion/*"
  ],
  "declarative_net_request": {
    "rule_resources": [
      {
        "id": "ruleset_1",
        "enabled": true,
        "path": "rules.json"
      }
    ]
  },
  "browser_specific_settings": {
    "gecko": {
        "id": "email@commonmail.com",
        "strict_min_version": "113.0"
    }
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.example.net/discussion/*"],
      "css": ["aspect-ratio-hotfix.css"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Rules.json

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {
      "type": "redirect",
      "redirect": {
        "regexSubstitution": "https://www.example.net/discussion/data/avatars/o\\1"
      }
    },
    "condition": {
      "regexFilter": "^https://www.example.net/discussion/data/avatars/[lsm](.*)$"
    }
  }
]
```

Unable to install to Firefox on **addons** page.
[image: This extension cannot be installed because it is not verified]

> This extension cannot be installed because it is not verified

Installing in **debugging** is possible - It does not work and show no error.

Comment: Can you give us a translation of the error message?

Comment: Sure, "This extension cannot be installed because it is not verified"

Comment: It's a permission problem, see https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/modifyheaders-with-updatedynamicrules-doesnt-work-on-firefox-using-manifest-v3/120530

Comment: It really a permission problem. I have been modifying the code for the whole week...